# WebBrowser Control keep crushing, how to log it?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, logging, webbrowser-control

I have a problem with my simple wpf application.
My wpf app just used as container to a WebBrowser control, and a speicel refresh button (with a little code behind).

after a while (may be a few days) suddenly the application crush end exit. 
the funny thing is that the app didn't crush when we used Windows Forms container.

So because the only code is in the button clicked event and int the constractor, and the app doesn't crush there I can't log the problem, any one knows how to catch a general exception just before the applicatio exit so i can log it?

thank a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: That Excectly what i needed! Thank you!